# In jQuery, what's the difference between text() and innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div elements and hold text/string inside them, then I try to iterate them, and text() doesn't work, but innerHTML work just fine.

```
var arr = $('div.elm');
$.each(arr, function(i,j){
    alert(j.text()); // it's not working

    console.log(j.text()); // nothing's in log

    alert(j.innerHTML); // works fine!
});
```

Comment: what kind of elements are you iterating over?

Comment: `<div class='elm'>text1</div>` ... and so on..

Comment: sometimes you need to re-jquerify :) iterated items... try `$(j).text()`

Comment: j is not a jQuery object so text() can't be used, you need to wrap it first

Comment: @AbdullahBattal: I think "re-jquerify" may be the most awkward made-up programming word I've ever seen. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text()` is a jQuery method, `innerHTML` is an DOM Element attribute.

When you call [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) on a jQuery object, the second parameter you receive (the element) will be a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

- The jQuery [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method is similar to calling `innerText`/`textContent` on a HTML Element.
- The jQuery [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method is similar to calling `innerHTML` on a HTML Element.

If you want to use jQuery methods on your parameter passed in by `each`, you have to wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
$.each(arr, function(i,j){
    alert($(j).text());
});
```

Comment: I didn't down vote because I don't really think this is down vote worthy, but jQuery `text()` isn't equivalent to `innerText`.  Internally, jQuery iterates over the descendant nodes pulling the `nodeValue` from CDATA and TextNodes. The result would be the same for most cases, but you might find some white-space differences in others.  Also, not all browsers support `innerText`, instead they implement the standards-compliant `textContent`.

Comment: @AndyE: Ah, I should really have checked before I made something like that up... Thanks for the correction, I've reworded the answer :).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you should wrap the object in a jQuery object to use the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$.each(arr, function(i,j){
    alert($(j).text()); 

    console.log($(j).text()); 

    alert(j.innerHTML); 
});
```

`innerHTML` is an element attribute.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/text/

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
>   documents. The result of the .text() method is a **string containing the
>   combined text** of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
>   parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
>   and other white space.)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the original question, does it?

Answer (score 1):

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) returns JUST the text of that element and all of its descendant elements, where as `.innerHTML` returns all of the HTML in that element.

Comment: Correct, but incomplete. The real issue is that `text()` and `innerHTML` operate on completely different objects.